# how to hide input of type radio in html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide all the tags in html that are `<input type=radio>`

I had this css

```
input{display: none}
```

However, this is hiding even buttons because they are `<input type=button>`

is there a way to hide just intput of type radio?

I can use jquery if need be but if it can be done via js or better yet just CSS then I'll prefer that...

I am using IE6 so no CSS3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of your need to support IE 6, you can use jQuery:

```js
$( "input[type='radio']" ).css( "display", "none" );
// Or call the .hide() method
```

In more modern browsers, you can use the attribute selector:

```css
input[type=radio] { display: none }
```

Answer (score 3):

This jQuery snippet does the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":radio").hide();       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type="radio"]{display:none;}
```

I don't think this is CSS3. Should be CSS2.

Comment: Just checked on Quirksmode - not available in IE6: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selector_attribute.html

Comment: CSS 2.1.  IE 6 doesn't support it unfortunately.

Comment: Apparently the importance of jQuery is mainly to let us perform such tasks also in IE6 :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is easily accomplished with CSS Attribute selectors but those are [not supported by IE6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx#attributeselectors).

The only other way to do it with CSS would be to give all your input radio elements a common CSS classname and use that to select in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery:

```
$("input[type='radio']").hide()
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery, straight up Javascript would be...

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    if(inputs[i].type == 'radio')
        inputs[i].style.display = 'none';
```

Personally, I think the jQuery version is better, but if you don't want to include the library it this is your answer.

Answer (score -1):

A simple JavaScript solution that should work on IE6:

```
function hideAllRadioButtons()
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    {
        var e = elems[i];
        if (e.type === 'radio')
        {
            e.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```